# What are the correct Travis API calls (or library methods) to first start and watch a build and later retrieve its status and build log?

Tags: travis-ci, travis-rb, travis-ci-api

In one of my applications, I want to trigger a Travis CI build, "watch" the build as it is scheduled, run and finishes, then retrieve the final build state and the build log to output it in my app.

I started by [triggering a build with the API](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/triggering-builds/), which gives me a `Request` and its `request.id`. This works perfectly.

- Then I can retrieve this `Request`, which includes the `Request.state` and an embedded `Build` and its `Build.id` along with the `Build.state`, using the [`/repo/.../request/#id` endpoint](https://developer.travis-ci.org/resource/request).
- I could then start polling [`/build/#id` endpoint](https://developer.travis-ci.org/resource/build) to monitor the state every second.
- As soon as the build is finished, I can use the `Job` that is part of the `Build` (when requested from `/build/#id`) to download the log from [`/job/#id/log`](https://developer.travis-ci.org/resource/log) and display it in my application.

This all sounds pretty inefficient.

Is there a better way to achieve this?
Is there a "quicker way" (= less requests) from creating the `request` to `log`?
Can I avoid the manual polling somehow?

Comment: have you checked this: https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/notifications ?
I don't know how your application is supposed to work but my idea is the following: use a basic http server with a static IP. If your application is supposed to be distributed then this will be a bit more complicated but not impossible.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, I indeed planned to run the app on many different machines, so webhooks weren't really considered. But I looked at it again now: The `id` of the webhook seems to be the `Build.id`, so this could definitely replace the polling part. On the other hand I would need a stateful server component of course that my app could poll or listen to. Maybe, if I don't find anything better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will use this answer to document my own research that might help resolve this:

1. Travis CI API supports [eager loading via `?include`](https://developer.travis-ci.org/eager-loading#eager%20loading). Using this, I can already get the `Job.id` in the `Request` response via the extended `Build` objects: `?include=request.builds` - I don't have to do another request to `build` endpoint for the `Job.id`. But as I need to poll for status changes, this doesn't really help much.
2. As @Maël Pedretti suggested in the comments, Travis supports [webhook notifications](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/notifications#configuring-webhook-notifications). The [submitted object](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/notifications#webhooks-delivery-format) contains an `id` which is the `Build.id`,  so this could replace the polling part I described above. As my app doesn't just run on one server that can be configured as the webhook url though, I need a stateful server component that my app could poll or listen to. So just a horse trade :/